# Check dimensions of uploading file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have file uploader component where I need to add dimensions validator

Here is code of validator

```
   export const filesDimensionValidator =
  (maxWidth: number, maxHeight: number): ValidatorFn =>
  (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const value: IUploadFileControl = control.value;

    if (value == null) {
      return null;
    }

    for (const x of value.allFiles) {
      if (x.size > maxFileSize) {
        return { file_max_size: VALIDATION_LABEL_ATTACHMENT_MAX_SIZE };
      }
    }

    return null;
  };
```

if for loop `x` parameter has `File` type.

Here will be only images.

How I can get the width and height of the image within this file?

Comment: do you mean the `width` and `height` of the image?

Comment: @TachibanaShin yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Image` to create an image and then get needed dimensions.

You can use `file.type` to validate if `x` is an image:

Try this:

```
// add mime type check
if (x?.type.includes('image/')) {
  
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(x);
  const img = new Image();

  img.onload = function () {
    console.log(img.width, img.height);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
  };

  img.src = url;

}
```

*edit*

get dimensions synchronously:

```
// pass file to the method and hold execution
console.log(await this.getDimensions(x));

// method that gets and return dimensions from a file
  getDimensions(x: File) : Promise<{width:number, height:number}> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(x);
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = () => {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
        resolve({ width: img.width, height: img.height });
      };
      img.src = url;
    });
  }
```

Comment: but how I can get width and height outside of `img.onload = function () `?

Comment: not sure what you mean, you can store it in variable/service etc., if you maybe want to perform validation synchronously in the loop, well, maybe move this to async method and then await the dimensions..

Comment: `for (const x of value.allFiles) {
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(x);
      const img = new Image();
      let width: number;
      let height: number;

      img.onload = function () {
        width = img.width;
        height = img.height;
        URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
      };

      console.log(width!, height!);
      img.src = url;
    }`


outside `onload`  variables `width`  and `height` -  undefined

Comment: that's because `img.onload` is async, so it logs undefined before it get's assigned in `onload`, so you need to return it from `onload`, or maybe move the code to a separate method

Comment: try the updated code, added separate method that gets dimensions synchronously